# POST request for adding a new field in json-server

Tags: javascript, api, post, json-server

There is an endpoint called `/data` which contains some fields. How can I create a new field in this endpoint?
before:

```
{
  "data": {
    "name": "...",
    "surname": "..."
  }
}
```

after the `api.post('/data', { email })` request, `/data` should look like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "name": "...",
    "surname": "...",
    "email": "..."
  }
}
```

but currently, when I add a new field, the other ones are being deleted:

```
{
  "data": {
    "email": "..."
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are only passing email, as mentioned by you:

> api.post('/data', { email })

If you mean appending email in body of post request :

```
let data ={name, surname} //suppose    
api.post('/data', { ...data,email });
```

Comment: The remaining fields are initially stored in `/data`, only the `email` needs to be added without touching the others

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want that the `/data` endpoint remembers the previous REST calls, and simply adds/overwrites object key/values. Because REST is stateless you need a persistent storage to achieve that, such as MySQL, MongoDB, or Memcached.